# UIAlertView is too bookkeeping to replace in iOS8 when SDK target is iOS7

Tags: ios, uialertview, deprecated, uialertcontroller

UIAlertview has been deprecated, replaced by UIAlertController. it's a mess to support both iOS7 and iOS8.

What's Apple's viewpoint, when the deployment target is iOS7. Can I use UIAlertView for both ? Has anyone got their app rejected for this reason ?

thanks !

Comment: There is no reason not to keep using just `UIAlertView`. Once you drop support for iOS 7, switch to `UIAlertController`.

Comment: Hey Thanks ! that's what I kinda hoped. No way to support iOS7 without declaring <UIAlerViewDelegate> in a code that'll run on iOS8. I'm not sure what apple folks wanted to achieve by deprecating these classes, but frankly, that's just a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article out, the author explains pretty nicely apples thinking on the matter and it does kind of make sense.

Basically the change helps unify alerts across iOS, it is actually pretty neat.

http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/

You can just use UIAlertView for both still, but it could get messy in future.

Comment: I certainly agree with what Matt T, but why would that get messy ? When iOS9 comes, it'll be time to drop ios7 support, and everything will be fine ? no ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same concern, particularly when there is the possibility for this SDK to be used in an iOS 8 extension while simultaneously wanting that same SDK to support iOS 7 for non-extension uses.

It was the motivation for an open-source project I undertook to back-port UIAlertController to iOS 7.

Have a look: [JVAlertController](http://www.github.com/jverdi/JVAlertController)